# Name for tendency of negative morphemes to climb to "outermost" position

Tags: syntax, negation

In a few languages (the examples are from English), it seems to be common for negative morphemes to modify a verb that's "higher" in the syntactic structure of a sentence (not sure what the correct word is for directions in a tree). This causes the negative morpheme to be modifying a different verb than what you would expect if negation were strictly compositional.

For instance (1) is an utterance a native English speaker might produce, but (2a/b) would only be produced in very restricted contexts, such as a humorous answer to a question.

```
(1) I don't want to buy an apple.

(2a) *I want not to buy an apple. / (2b) *I want to not buy an apple.
```

This can also occur in cases where you have a dependent clause. To my ear, (3) and (4) mean approximately the same thing, although the emphasis is different. In particular, I do not interpret (3) to mean or be consistent with "I don't know whether the Earth is flat or not".

```
(3) I don't think that the Earth is flat.

(4) I think that the Earth is not flat.
```

This is sort of an interesting phenomenon, since it makes the meaning of negation non-compositional. Does it have a name? Are there languages that don't exhibit this tendency to move negative morphemes around?

Here's an example in French.

```
(5) Il ne faut pas réveiller le chat qui dort.
It is necessary not to wake the cat that sleeps.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The phenomenon is known as NEG-raising.

Comment: Yes. There's a vast literature on it, which is [summarized and discussed](http://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/001498/current.pdf) here. [Negation in general](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) is a much bigger and more complex phenomenon than you might expect.